# Extend bottom div container upwards into top container div using CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make top the image container smaller by pushing the bottom grey container upwards to reduce the height of the SVG:

[image]

So that it looks like the following:

[image]

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card__media">
        <img src="/widget.svg" alt="err"></div>
    <div class="card__content-container">
        <div class="card__header-body-container">
            <div class="card__header">
                <div class="card__header-container">
                    <div class="card__title-container">
                        <h6 class="card__title">Title</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card__body">
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried playing with the margins, padding and z-index to try do this but I cannot get it correct

Codesandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-ives-qidvy6?file=/src/Example/Example.js

Comment: You tag this as CSS and that appears to be the crux of your question yet include no CSS in your question.  Might I suggest you do that and include it in a snippet perhaps?

Comment: An example sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-ives-qidvy6?file=/src/Example/Example.js

Comment: @KeithM Try using the `aspect-ratio` property on the image container along with `object-fit: cover`.

Answer (score 0):

First off forgive my use of annoying colors, borders and backgrounds - these are just to show what is where.

Key here is I made the whole `card-container` a 12w X 8h "grid" then put the image in row 1 through 5 and then overlay the `card__content-container` on top of that starting in row 5.

This is the key CSS part here:

```
.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8 1fr);
}
.card-image {
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}

.card__content-container {
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  grid-row: 5 / span 6;
  background-color: #dddddd88;
}
```

```css
.card-parent {
  display: grid;
  place-items: cemter;
  background-color: #ffdddd88;
}

.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8 1fr);
}

.card-image {
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}

.card__content-container {
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  grid-row: 5 / span 6;
  background-color: #dddddd88;
}

.card__header-body-container {
  background-color: #ddddff88;
}

.card__header-container {
  border: solid 4px;
  border-color: #FF000066;
}

.card__header {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.card__title {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #2222ff44;
  color: blue;
}

.card__title {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.card__content-container {
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  grid-row: 5 / span 6;
  background-color: #dddddd88;
}

.card__header {
  background-color: #ddffdd88;
}

.card__body {
  background-color: #44444422;
  color: white;
}


/* not present
.card__footer {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="card card-parent">
  <div class="card__media card-container">
    <!-- <img src="/widget.svg" alt="err"></div> -->
    <img class="card-image" src="https://svgshare.com/i/qh5.svg" alt="err">
    <div class="card__content-container">
      <div class="card__header-body-container">
        <div class="card__header">
          <div class="card__header-container">
            <div class="card__title-container">
              <h6 class="card__title">Title</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card__body">
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```